# Adding new values in AChartEngine charts

Tags: android, achartengine

Is there a way to dynamically add data to the **original** series in a chart (right now, I'm trying to add new data to a line chart when panned but the question is broader)? Adding a **new** series works all right, I can create a new `XYSeries` and even reuse the `XYSeriesRenderer` to have the same display. When added to the chart, it will display but, obviously, as a new series, meaning that it won't join seamlessly with the previous data and displayed values above the line will be duplicated.

If I keep the dataset, the series renderer and the series itself and try to re-use them later, I get a seemingly endless loop when I try to `series.add(x, y)` my new values, the program never returns. I also tried to `dataset.removeSeries(series)` before adding the new values and `dataset.addSeries(series)` again but in vain.

**Update with code:**

The chart is set up like this:

```
renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
renderer.setAntialiasing(true);
...
renderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);

dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

seriesRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
seriesRenderer.setColor(chartColor);
...
seriesRenderer.setChartValuesTextSize(...);
renderer.addSeriesRenderer(seriesRenderer);

series = new XYSeries("");
...
series.add(x, y);
...
dataset.addSeries(series);
```

Called in PanListener.panApplied:

```
dataset.removeSeries(series);
...
series.add(x, y);
...
dataset.addSeries(series);
```

Comment: Please post some code and mention the ACE version you are using.

Comment: Version is 1.1.0. I'll try to edit some code into the question but it's not really easy because it's already woven completely into an application... :-)

Comment: Basically, as far as I can tell, the only difference from the version that works (and the sample one you also have in your source, the chart builder one) is  this: inside `panApplied()`, instead of creating a `new XYSeries`, adding the new values to it and adding this new series to the chart, I try to re-use the original `series` object.

Comment: Why do you remove the series and add it back? Just modify the contents of the current series.

Comment: It was an attempt to make it work. With or without, I get the same non-returning call. As soon as I call `series.add()` from `panApplied()`, the first call never returns and I can see endless allocations in LogCat.

Comment: It's now that I revisited this program of mine with the intention of some upgrades. As far as I can tell know, the actual problem seems to be that if I use `series.add()` to add new values to the *beginning* of the series (panning to the left, that is), the indexes get disturbed. First, the chart values displayed will jump from item to item during panning (although the actual XYChart displayed points stay correct). And this also leads to cases when `startIndex` passed down between the various `drawXXX()` functions becomes -1, resulting in an exception.

Comment: When I add new values with `series.add()` that happen to be *before* the values already there, the chart line is drawn correctly (`drawSeries()`) but the chart values called from it (`drawChartValuesText()`) are wrong. The connection between chart value and its value display is no longer reliable and fixed.

Comment: Yet in other words: `series.getY(startIndex)` as called from `XYChart.drawChartValuesText()` no longer returns the actual value corresponding to the actual point in the series.

Comment: @Dan, I found a solution to this issue, if you want to take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To recoup the problem: the chart in question is `XYChart`. When I pan to the right and add new items to the series using `XYSeries.add()` that lie **before** the already existing values, although the renewing chart line itself displays OK, the chart values displayed above the individual chart points no longer keep in sync with the new values. This is how I solved it by modifying the source.

The problem in the source was that `XYChart.drawChartValuesText()`receives a `startIndex` argument and uses it to look up the values for the labels to display using `XYSeries.getY()` and this is where things go wrong. So, in the large `XYChart.draw()`function, before we actually call `drawSeries()`, I set up a new variable:

```
final List<Double> chartValues = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

In addition to the `values` list later, I add the actual value to this list as well:

```
values.add(xValue);
values.add(yValue);
chartValues.add(yValue);
```

and pass it when calling the next function (this happens twice in the source):

```
drawSeries(series, canvas, paint, points, seriesRenderer, yAxisValue, i, or, startIndex, chartValues);
```

`XYChart.drawSeries()`, in turn, passes it along to:

```
drawChartValuesText(canvas, series, seriesRenderer, paint, pointsList, seriesIndex, startIndex, values);
```

Finally, `XYChart.drawChartValuesText()` uses these new values instead of the `startIndex`-based lookup:

```
protected void drawChartValuesText(Canvas canvas, XYSeries series, XYSeriesRenderer renderer, Paint paint, List<Float> points, int seriesIndex, int startIndex, List<Double> values) {
  if (points.size() > 2) { // there are more than one point
    // record the first point's position
    float previousPointX = points.get(0);
    float previousPointY = points.get(1);
    for (int k = 0; k < points.size(); k += 2)
      if (k == 2) { // decide whether to display first two points' values or not
        if (Math.abs(points.get(2) - points.get(0)) > renderer.getDisplayChartValuesDistance() || Math.abs(points.get(3) - points.get(1)) > renderer.getDisplayChartValuesDistance()) {
          // first point
          drawText(canvas, getLabel(renderer.getChartValuesFormat(), values.get(k)), points.get(0), points.get(1) - renderer.getChartValuesSpacing(), paint, 0);
          // second point
          drawText(canvas, getLabel(renderer.getChartValuesFormat(), values.get(k + 1)), points.get(2), points.get(3) - renderer.getChartValuesSpacing(), paint, 0);

          previousPointX = points.get(2);
          previousPointY = points.get(3);
        }
      }
      else if (k > 2)
        // compare current point's position with the previous point's, if they are not too close, display
        if (Math.abs(points.get(k) - previousPointX) > renderer.getDisplayChartValuesDistance() || Math.abs(points.get(k + 1) - previousPointY) > renderer.getDisplayChartValuesDistance()) {
          drawText(canvas, getLabel(renderer.getChartValuesFormat(), values.get(k / 2)), points.get(k), points.get(k + 1) - renderer.getChartValuesSpacing(), paint, 0);
          previousPointX = points.get(k);
          previousPointY = points.get(k + 1);
        }
  }
  else
    for (int k = 0; k < points.size(); k += 2)
      drawText(canvas, getLabel(renderer.getChartValuesFormat(), values.get(k / 2)), points.get(k), points.get(k + 1) - renderer.getChartValuesSpacing(), paint, 0);
}
```

This workaround seems to solve the problem for me now but I report back if I find anything problematic with it later.

Answer (score 0):

If the start point of your new series is the end point of the old series, you probably ran in the same problem as me:

I also encountered an endless loop in XYSeries.add(x,y), when adding a second x/y pair having the same x value as a previous pair. In my case x is of type long and represents a time stamp.
The reason for the endless loop can be easily found in the source code of the method:

```
public synchronized void add(double x, double y) {
  while (mXY.get(x) != null) {
    // add a very small value to x such as data points sharing the same x will
    // still be added
    x += getPadding(); // Defined as constant: PADDING = 0.000000000001
   }
   mXY.put(x, y);
   updateRange(x, y);
 }
```

If x is so big, that adding the very small "padding" does not change the value of x, the condition in the while loop never changes. (A double does not really change if the increment is too small.)

I avoided the problem by making sure, not to add the same x value twice.

Comment: I also filed an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/issues/detail?id=357) in the ACE bugtracker. Solution would be simply to use `x += Math.ulp(x)` instead of `x += getPadding()`

Comment: I checked in a fix for this issue.